# Finding a representation of a group is the same as finding a matrix for each element of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

"Finding a representation of a group is the same as finding a matrix for each element of the group"

Is there any restrictions to the above? Does the group have to be finite?

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less correct, but there's a lot more to it than that. The most important thing being that the group multiplication must correspond to matrix multiplication: so if $f(x)$ is the matrix corresponding to group element $x$, then you need that $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.

In other words, if $V$ is the object on which you want a representation, and $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$ is the group of automorphisms of $V$, then a representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism $f: G \to \mathrm{Aut}(V)$. In the special case where you are looking at a finite-dimensional vector space with a basis, then $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$ is (essentially) a set of invertible matrices, and then $f$ assigns a matrix to each group element.

To sum up, the statement is correct if it is understood that we are talking about *representations on finite dimensional vector spaces*, and it is understood that this association needs to respect the group multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

No, although that sentence requires some explanation. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over some field $F$. Let $B$ be a basis of $V$. Then a representation of a group $G$ on $V$ is a group homomorphism $\rho$ from $G$ into the group $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ of all (linear) automorphisms of $V$. And then, for each $g\in G$, we have the matrix $M(g)$ of $\rho(g)$ with respect to $B$. That's a way of defining $\rho$: for each $g\in G$, we take a matrix $M(g)\in\mathrm{GL}(n,F)$ and we define $\rho(g)$ as the automorphism of $V$ whose matrix with respect to $B$ is $M(g)$. This will always work as long as$$(\forall g_1,g_2\in G):M(g_1g_2)=M(g_1).M(g_2).$$